# Is it possible to convert nvarchar to int?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tried something like this:

```
select PREPRO = case when (isnumeric(PREPRO) = 1 and 
PREPRO in ('0','1','-1')) or 
convert(varchar, PREPRO) in ('True','False')
then convert(bit, convert(integer, PREPRO)) else 'No' end
from dbo.TI10SE
```

The PREPRO contains all "False".

I get this error:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'False' to data type int.

Does it mean that an nvarchar can not be converted to an integer ever? I guess its because some data may be lost.

Comment: It is nvarchar. Its not possible is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE to accomplish this:

```
DECLARE @PREPRO VARCHAR(5)
SET @PREPRO = 'False'
SELECT CASE WHEN @PREPRO = 'False' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I have done. I trusted the code I saw as it was written by a senior person and tried to use it but then realised its not possible to convert nvarchar to int.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to convert your `PREPRO` to an integer, even if the value it holds is `True` or `False`:

```
convert(integer, PREPRO)
```

You cannot convert the value `False` to an integer.

The conditional in your when clause evaluates to true when `PREPRO` is a number within 0, 1, -1 **OR** when it evaluates to either `True` or `False`. In **any** of these cases, you attempt to convert this value to an integer and then to a bit.

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar can be converted to an integer if it contains an integer

```
DECLARE @PREPRO VARCHAR(5)
SET @PREPRO = '10'

SELECT CONVERT(integer, @PREPRO)
```

T-SQL doesn't know what to associate with 'False' or 'True', so you will have to use a CASE statement like rdkleine said.

Also in this statement:

```
convert(bit, convert(integer, PREPRO)) else 'No' end
```

You're going to receive an error, because 'No' is not of type bit, what are you trying to return?